# Browse into Session attribute

Tags: scala, simulation, jsonpath, gatling

I'm trying to check if the responses of my regex are in my JSON. For that I stored the regex response into a variable metas. Now i need to browse into this variable to compare with all the values of metas and I don't figure out how to write this. \"${metas(\"${nbr_metas}\")}\" doesn't seem to be working.

here how i am doing:

```
   val scn_get_content   = scenario("Test")
    .exec(http("get metas")
    .get(url+"/"+json_file)
    .check(status.is(200))
    .check(regex("\"([^\"]*)\":").findAll.saveAs("metas")))
    .pause(1) 

    .repeat("${metas.size()}", "nbr_metas") {        
    exec(http("Get JSON")
    .get(url_json)
    .headers(headers_1)
    .check(status.is(200)) 
    .check(responseTimeInMillis.lessThan(1000))
    .check(jsonPath("$.\"${metas(\"${nbr_metas}\")}\".findAll").exists))
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have yet encountered the same problem, and finally found the solution.

```
.foreach("${url}", "session_url", "counter")(
    exec(http("url")
    .get("${url(counter)}")
    .headers(headers_1)
    .check(status.is(200))
    ))
```

in my example url is a session attribute and counter is the counter...

hope it'll help some people!

Comment: For such a simple use case, you'd better use foreach! http://gatling.io/docs/2.1.4/general/scenario.html#foreach

Answer (score 0):

For checks on JSON documents, you'd better use [JsonPath checks](http://gatling.io/docs/2.1.3/http/http_check.html#http-response-body).

Comment: first of all, thanks for the reply. in the first part i am using regex because i need the keys and not the value in my JSON, in the second part i'm using jsonpath. But i don't know how to write this...  .check(jsonPath("$.\"${metas(\"${nbr_metas}\")}\".findAll").exists)) do you have any clue?